# Code Review Blog Library

Tags: discussion

I really enjoy reading some of the answers posted by Code Review users.  Where can I go to get more helpful advice for improving my code from these users?

Let's list a few off-site resources authored by Code Review users which address some of the common problems we see in code.  To keep this organized, please post one blog per answer.  Answers should include a link to the blog, a link to the user, and may include a table of contents for blog articles.

Comment: What are the rules on blogs? Do they have to be only about programming?

Comment: They should be relevant to code review.  If only part of the content is relevant, that *might* be okay, but I guess we can also let down & upvotes on the answers indicate how useful we consider the content relative to Code Review's scope.

Comment: It would be useful if every blog was tagged with the languages it is covering

Comment: Perhaps.  I don't know about the others, but mine isn't *generally* specific to a language.  I may use a specific language for code snippets, but the general point being addressed by *most* of the articles is language-agnostic.

Comment: Why does the question contain the answers? This removes the voting aspects. Use a code snippet if you want to make an easy list, like they do on PPCG.

Comment: @Pimgd You're going to have to either provide a link or just edit it to show me what you're talking about.  As far as the answer to `"Why"`, it's based on other similar meta questions *on Code Review*.

Comment: @nhgrif http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet

Answer (score 8):

## [Loki Astari](http://lokiastari.com/)

Authored by [Loki Astari](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/507/loki-astari)

Answer (score 6):

## [importBlogKit](http://importblogkit.com)

Authored by [nhgrif](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/36366/nhgrif)

- [Writing Readable Code](http://importblogkit.com/2015/03/writing-readable-code/)
- [There are 10 types of people in this world…](http://importblogkit.com/2015/03/10-types-of-people/)
- [ALL YOUR SOURCE ARE CONTROL BY US](http://importblogkit.com/2015/04/source-control/)
- [Programming, Objectively](http://importblogkit.com/2015/04/programming-objectively/)
- [How do you eat an elephant?](http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/)
- [Developing User Interfaces](http://importblogkit.com/2015/06/developing-ui/)
- [Does Not Work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)
- [The Ten Commandments of Programming](http://importblogkit.com/2015/08/ten-commandments/)
- [Unit Tests Don't Prevent Bugs](http://importblogkit.com/2016/01/unit-tests-dont-prevent-bugs/)
- [How to ask a good Stack Overflow question.](http://importblogkit.com/2016/03/how-to-ask-a-good-stack-overflow-question/)

New posts announced on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/@importBlogKit).

Comment: "How do you eat an elephant" is a must-read for many beginners. I love referring to that post.

Answer (score 6):

## [Journal of daily hacks](http://www.janosgyerik.com/blog/)

Authored by [@Janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12390/janos?tab=profile).

Featured articles (somewhat related to code review, the practice; newer to older):

- [Lessons learned from The Clean Coder](http://www.janosgyerik.com/lessons-learned-from-the-clean-coder/)
- [Favorite chapters of Code Complete](http://www.janosgyerik.com/my-favorite-chapters-of-code-complete/)
- [Checklists from Code Complete](http://www.janosgyerik.com/checklists-from-the-book-code-complete/)
- [Cleaning Java projects with Eclipse and plugins](http://www.janosgyerik.com/cleaning-java-projects-with-eclipse-and-plugins/)

New posts announced on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/janosgyerik).

Answer (score 3):

## [418 Status](http://418stat.us/tags/code)

Authored by [Quill](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62429/quill)

Answer (score 3):

## [Random Lyle](http://randomlyle.blogspot.com/)

Authored by [Malachi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/18427/malachi?tab=profile)

Featured Articles

- [Logo Coding with KTurtle](http://randomlyle.blogspot.com/2014/09/logo-coding-with-kturtle.html) about one of the first [logo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logo) questions on Code Review
- [Our Mission is Complete](http://randomlyle.blogspot.com/2014/09/our-mission-is-complete.html)
- [Code Review Graduation!](http://randomlyle.blogspot.com/2014/09/code-review-graduation.html)
- [Null-safe Dereference in C# 6.0](http://randomlyle.blogspot.com/2016/03/null-safe-derefence-in-c.html)